# "No endpoint listening" when Accessing axis2 webservice from .net client

Tags: .net, web-services, apache-axis

I have to consume data from axis2 webservice. I added it's URI to Service References folder in my .NET client and I can view all methods and fields of this webservice in Object Browser tab. But when I am trying to use it's method i recive error:

```
"There was no endpoint listening at http://my_service_url that could accept the
message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action."
```

I am sure that address is correct since I can see this WS in object browser but it isnt working. Obviously I lack knowledge in this area, but I wasnt able to get help via google. I would appreciate for any tip.

PS. I am using VS 2008 and C#

Answer (score 2, accepted):

please check endpoint of the service.
u have to define endpoint in web.config file

Answer (score 1):

Try visiting the web service in a browser to make sure it's there.  Axis2 may have a page that lets you call the methods on the service with parameters.

I have a feeling the problem is that you are asking for a SOAP action that it doesn't support.